# Change the interpreter in Pycharm but it doesn't work

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I changed the interpreter from python3.7 to python2.7 in Pycharm. But after I did this process, the interpreter showed success but actually, when I ran the code it still was running with python 3.7.

The interpreters are set from the anaconda.

This image shows that I have changed the external library to Python 2.7 but when I test the type of python in the terminal, it still shows in Python3.7.

I really struggle about this problem, hope someone can help me.

[image]

Comment: Terminal window uses your default commmand-prompt where python command might point to python3 executable. So even if you change the interpreter it wont change anything. If you want to use python2 then you have to use: `python2 code.py`. But I would suggest changing your interpreter to a python2 venv.

Comment: Yes, in the interpreter setting I have changed the virtual env to python27 which is set by the anaconda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you face a known PyCharm bug: [PY-23417](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23417). IDE fails to activate the conda environment in the terminal so you end up running Python 2 instead of 3 by `python` executable as it uses the first interpreter in `PATH`.

Try PyCharm [2019.1 EAP build](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/). The problem should be resolved there.

Comment: Thank you! you are correct, after I download the new version my problem had been solved